# nesting issue with GridLayout

Tags: android

In the xml below I am trying to  create a layout as in the image below.

I have used a GridLayout. In the last view on the right I am trying to put in two text areas and two labels but I am not able to do it.

can you please help me?  Thanks

[image: form concept]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:columnCount="8"
  android:rowCount="7" 
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

<!--  row -->
  <View android:layout_rowSpan="7" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_width="50dp" android:background="#224455" /><!--  spacer col -->

  <TextView android:text=" name: " android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1"  />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_width="200dp" />

  <View android:layout_rowSpan="7" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_width="50dp" android:background="#224455" /><!--  spacer col -->

  <TextView android:text=" email: " android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1"  />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_width="200dp" />

  <View android:layout_rowSpan="7" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_width="50dp" android:background="#224455" /><!--  spacer col -->

<!--  row first end  takes up 5 rows NB: -->
  <View android:layout_rowSpan="7" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_width="500dp" android:background="#666666" >


<!--  how to add here????????????????????????   two text areas and two labels -->



  </View>

  <!-- row spacer -->
    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_height="20dp"  />
  <TextView android:text="" android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_height="20dp"  />
    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_height="20dp"  />
  <TextView android:text="" android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_height="20dp"  />
  <!-- row spacer -->

  <!-- row -->
    <TextView android:text=" name: " android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1"  />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_width="200dp" />
    <TextView android:text=" name: " android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1"  />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_width="200dp" />
  <!-- row -->

  <!-- row spacer -->
    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_height="20dp"  />
  <TextView android:text="" android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_height="20dp"  />
    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_height="20dp"  />
  <TextView android:text="" android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_height="20dp"  />
  <!-- row spacer -->

  <!-- row -->
    <TextView android:text=" name: " android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1"  />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_width="200dp" />
    <TextView android:text=" name: " android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1"  />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_width="200dp" />
  <!-- row -->  

  <!-- row spacer -->
    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_height="20dp"  />
  <TextView android:text="" android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_height="20dp"  />
    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_height="20dp"  />
  <TextView android:text="" android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1" android:layout_height="20dp"  />
  <!-- row spacer -->

  <!-- row -->
    <TextView android:text=" name: " android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1"  />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_width="200dp" />
    <TextView android:text=" name: " android:layout_rowSpan="1" android:layout_colSpan="1"  />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_width="200dp" />
  <!-- row -->
```

Comment: Grid layout is bad , you better use `LinearLayout` and weights

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. Is there any chance that you can show me an example with nesting like this please?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ryanmclaren.com/home/android-nested-linearlayout-example/  [image]

Check this .....................................................................